# number of query values and destination fields not the same

Tags: vb.net

hello I'm looking to just do a simple reason for what this is not working ... i have tried adding the same column twice, taking out the TextBox2 i just cant get it to work. all that  works is if i take the last value out and the last column otherwise it will not work at all and i have now idea why.what i want is it to place a check mark in there to along with the name.
code:

```
Dim SqlText As String = "INSERT INTO tblEmployeeNames ([EmployeeName], 
        [UseForDropDown]) VALUES ('" & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & " " & 
         Trim(TextBox2.Text) & " " & (CheckBox1.Checked) & "')"
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Remember to never hire [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Answer (score 1):

You have included the checkbox-state with the first value, you need to separate them with a comma.

```
Dim SqlText As String = "INSERT INTO tblEmployeeNames ([EmployeeName], [UseForDropDown]) VALUES ('" & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & " " & Trim(TextBox2.Text) & "', " & (CheckBox1.Checked))"
```

Notice the Checked state doesn't require apostrophes around it.

See SLaks comment as well, you should be using parameterized queries.

Comment: Beat me to it. BTW, looks like you put a '.' instead of a ',' in your answer.

Comment: ok so i have taken the whole thing apart tried it again tried adding your code ... nothing  maybe i was unclear about what i was writing in its vb.net

Comment: Perhaps you should add to your question the whole code around this string and how do you use it